# Is there a way to set default capture device in Chrome like navigator.setUserMedia()? (GOOGLE CHROME)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam, webrtc

I am currently trying to switch the input video source being displayed but from what I have found, navigator.getUserMedia() can be used to get the localMediaStream but it only has a handle on one of each audio and video sources available to the browser.

Is there a way (using html or javascript) to set the default camera in Chrome if I have the device IDs?

Answer (score 2):

Check this demo:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/source/

Basically, you use MediaStreamTrack.getSources, pass the sourceId optional constraint to getUserMedia and you're good.
You can store the device ids, they stay the same until the cookies are cleared.